# Microsoft Graph API: Access token validation failure. Invalid audience

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jwt, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to migrate my app from Office 365 REST v2.0 to Microsoft Graph (v1.0). The token exchange seems to be working but as soon as I am trying to call an API, I am getting the following error:

```
    (
    [errorNumber] => 401
    [error] => Request returned HTTP error 401
    [message] => {
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-03-16T15:36:21",
      "request-id": "dda1e33a-2774-4986-8c45-1487404fbb72",
      "client-request-id": "e842d9a8-d71b-0563-f1ce-e58052e5bdb9"
    }
  }
}
)
```

The access_token has the following audience:

```
"aud": "https://outlook.office.com"
```

Here is the endpoint that I am using:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Payload:

```
grant_type=authorization_code
&code=0.AR8A3XwQy0FAmkSxxxx
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.com%2Fproxy%2Foffice365authorize
&client_id=e2147faf-87f0-4e7f-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx
&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means your token has the wrong audience, to call the Micrsoft Graph API, you need to get the token for Microsoft Graph i.e. the access token needs the `"aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com"`.

Looks you are using the [AAD auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get the token, so when you request an authorization code, use the scope with `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=xxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=xxxxxx
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

Also use `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` when requesting the token.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=xxxxxx
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&code=0.AR8A3XwQy0FAmkSxxxx
&redirect_uri=xxxxxx
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=xxxxx
```

To call the API successfully, also make sure you have [grant correct Delegated Microsoft Graph API permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#delegated-permission-to-microsoft-graph) for your client app depends on the API you want to call, e.g. if you want to call [`List users`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), you need the permissions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I add your suggestion, then the API throws this exception: `Message: AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope openid offline_access Calendars.ReadWrite https://graph.microsoft.com/.default is not valid. .default scope can't be combined with resource-specific scopes.`

Comment: @nimrod Remove `openid offline_access Calendars.ReadWrite` from `scope`, just `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` is enough as shown in my answer, it will get the token for all the MS Graph permissions added to the AD App by default.

Comment: I just found out that the app used another login url than I had configured, that caused the problem: scope=openid+offline_access+https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JoyWang It works but refresh token isn't returned one the `offline_access` scope is removed. Any idea how to go about this?