# Azure AD me profile

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, audience

I have error "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience."
For application set api permissions to offline_access, openid, profile, User.Read.
User start auth, go to MS auth site, ask about login, password and grand.

After exchange code to access token i well receive

```json
{'token_type': 'Bearer', 'scope': 'offline_access openid profile User.Read', 'expires_in': '3906', 'ext_expires_in': '3906', 'expires_on': '1653988700', 'not_before': '1653984493', 'resource': 'my_azure_client_id', ....}
```

Then i try get profile for current user with this access token.
As result i have error "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience."

Help pease)

**UPDATE**
Configured permissions
[image]

Comment: Could you please include scope you are using and 'aud' claim by decoding the token using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)?

Comment: I use aud with value = client_id.

Comment: Could you please include grant type you are using to generate the token?

Comment: grant_type = 'authorization_code'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind getting that error is because your token has **wrong audience**.

Please check what token you are using to call **Graph API**.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment***.
If you are using **`ID Token`** instead of **`Access Token`**, you may get error like below:

[image]

To know whether you are giving **access token** or **id token**, decode it in [JSON Web Tokens - jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).

For [**access token**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0gkv.png), **`aud`** claim will be `"https://graph.microsoft.com"` or `"00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"`

For [**id token**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58rEF.png), **`aud`** claim will be `"your_app_client_id"`

Choose the *access token* carefully with **`aud`** as `"https://graph.microsoft.com"` while calling **Microsoft Graph API:**

[image]

To get **[profile for current user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-signed-in-user-request)**, you can make use of below query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

I got the profile successfully using **access token** like below:

[image]

Replace your scope with **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`** while generating access token to avoid confusion.

**Reference:**

[oauth 2.0 - Microsoft Graph API: Access token validation failure. Invalid audience - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66658966/microsoft-graph-api-access-token-validation-failure-invalid-audience)

##### UPDATE:

In order to get authorization code, make the request by changing **scope** like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=your_client_id
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=xxxxxx
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

Comment: Thanks! You have right. How to get code for aud = https://graph.microsoft.com/

Comment: After change authorize request i recieve "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000". Then i make request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me with new access_token. Responce is Access token validation failure. Invalid audience. My reqest fot excachange code to access_token is https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/token with payload {'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'client_id': 'some_client_id', 'redirect_uri': '...', 'code': 'some_code', 'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/', 'client_secret': 'some_secret'}

Comment: Please note that "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" means **Azure AD Graph API** not **Microsoft Graph API**. Could you please include screenshot of API permissions you gave in Portal?

Comment: Try using [**v2.0 token endpoint**](https://i.imgur.com/jw0n1Kk.png) to get the access token !

Comment: After change version to "v2.0" aud is ok! But from metadata receive . But i have new problem like https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/14676 .

Comment: And token is ok. I make request to "me". Only "iss" field is incorrent.

Comment: What error you are getting now using that token while making request???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245247/discussion-between-sridevimachavarapu-mt-and-alexey-panevin).